# Search in two different types with different mappings in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Having the following mapping of the index `tester` with two types `items` and `items_two`:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tester?pretty=true' -d '{
  "mappings": {
      "items": {
         "properties" : {
           "body" : { "type": "string" }
}},
      "items_two": {
         "properties" : {
           "body" : { "type": "string" },
           "publised" : { "type": "integer"}
}}}}'
```

I put three elements on it.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tester/items/1?pretty=true' -d '{
     "body" : "Hey there im reading a book"
}'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tester/items_two/1?pretty=true' -d '{
     "body" : "I love the new book of my brother",
     "publised" : 0
}'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tester/items_two/2?pretty=true' -d '{
     "body" : "Stephen kings book is very nice",
     "publised" : 1
}'
```

I need to make a query that matches the word `book` and has `published = 1` AND the ones that has not `published` on the mapping, but has `book` on it (as the only item of `items`).

With the following query I only get match with the `"Stephen kings book is very nice"` item (obviously).

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tester/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
"query": {
 "bool": {
      "must": [
      {
            "match": { "body": "book" }
      },
      {
            "match": { "publised": "1" }
      }]
}}}'
```

My desired output if I search for the string `book` should match item #1 from the type `items` (`"Hey there im reading a book"`) and `item` #2 from the type `items_two` (`"Stephen kings book is very nice"`).

**I don't want to change the mapping or anything else**, I need to archieve this via one query, so how can I build my query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [_type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-type-field.html) field for these kind of searches. Try the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "body": "text"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "publised": "1"
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "_type": "items_two"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "body": "text"
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "_type": "items"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```